# Facebook API: Get the liked links

Tags: facebook, api, hyperlink, facebook-like

I am trying to get information on all links that a user has liked. in the past month.

I have obtained the user_likes permission from the user and am trying to use the FB Graph API.

I have tried:

/{user-id}/feed but it is only working for me not the users.

/{user-id}/likes but it only gives the pages, movies, apps, etc liked not the links likes.

/{user-id}/link doesn't give anything even when I see users have liked/shared a link.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do this in the Graph API. But you can use the FQL table `url_like` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/) to get your info:

```
select user_id, url from url_like where user_id=me()
```

Shares have nothing to do with URL likes imho...

Comment: Thanks Tobi. But this doesn't work either. This is tried:
(SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id=%s' % user_id) but doesn't return all links - only a few. any other suggestions.

Comment: You should use `me()` because this references the user from the actual access token you're using... Don't know what you are doing with `user_id=%s' % user_id` btw. The query works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: me() would work only to get the links for myself, right? I am trying to get the likes for everyone who is using my app.

Comment: `me()` applies to the actual Access Token, as I wrote! You cannot do this at once for all your app users, because this info is only requestable with a single User Access Token. This is basic stuff!

Comment: thanks Tobi. we have a FB app and used a function to get all urls liked by all users in our list. I am thinking that we might not have the correct permissions because of which we are not getting the right response.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You need the `user_likes` permission to be able to request the URL likes, as stated in the docs. And this permission is only give on User-level, not on application-level. If you loop through your Users and run this query for each one with his own Access Toke, this should work without a problem. There's no way to do this with one request!